# Use keys as variables in python

Tags: python, mongodb, document, mongoengine

I'm trying to remove the keys from a mongoengine Document in python:

```
document.update(unset__name=True)
document.update(unset__surname=True)
document.update(unset__dob=True)
...
```

but instead of the above I would like to loop through them and use a variable, something like:

```
document.update(unset__<key>=True)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: you can create a `dict` dynamically and then pass it to `document.update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, this is feasible by destructuring a dictionary.
For example, like in there:

```
d = { "p1": 11, "p2": 12}
def f(p1,p2):
    print(f"p1={p1}, p2={p2}")

f(p2=100,p1=10)
f(**d)
```

In your case, you will simply have to build a dictionnary with all the keys you want to destroy, by building the correct string:

```
def delete_key(key_name: str):
    d = { f"unset__{key_name}": True }
    document.update(**d)
```

Answer (score 1):

with a map ? you can build it and put as function kwargs

```py
unset_map = {
    "unset_key": True
}
document.update(**unset_map)
```

Comment: unpacking is not necessary